# Intercept incoming JMS messages to ActiveMQ, reject/approve based on rules

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Is there a feature in ActiveMQ, perhaps with Camel, to do the following?

- intercept incoming message at the **broker**
- validate headers and/or body based on arbitrary rules
- throw exception to sender if message not validated, or..
- reroute invalid messages to 'rejection' queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ActiveMQ broker Camel component to interceptor messages within the broker and route them using Camel routes

- http://activemq.apache.org/broker-camel-component.html

Comment: Looks good; possible to throw error/exception back to producer if message fails validation? What does the camel route look like in that case?

Answer (score 0):

reading your description, I presume you are trying to queue the incoming messages.

Have a new inner class, that implements MessageListener. Write a method that accepts some parameter and does some validation.

In the onMessage method, you can invoke the method passing appropriate parameter and if condition satisfies, queue the message,

In the parent method-
create an instance of this class and set the same to the setMessageListener.

Comment: I should have been clearer; intercept in the _broker_, not consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make incoming message interceptor:
1.In your ConnectionFactory:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url, username, password);
connectionFactory.getServerLocator().setIncomingInterceptorList("com.itsgosho.emails.EmailIncomingInterceptor");
```

2.In this interceptor:

```
@Component
public class EmailIncomingInterceptor implements org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.Interceptor {



@Override
public boolean intercept(Packet packet, RemotingConnection connection) throws ActiveMQException {

    if(isMessageReceive(packet)){
        Message message = ((SessionReceiveMessage) packet).getMessage();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean isMessageReceive(Packet packet){
    if (packet instanceof SessionReceiveMessage) {
        SessionReceiveMessage realPacket = (SessionReceiveMessage) packet;
        Message msg = realPacket.getMessage();
        if ((msg.getTimestamp() > 0) && msg.getUserID() != null){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```